# When creating the custom tensorflow Estimators, I got the ValueError: model_fn must include features argument

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to train a CNN. I wanted to use the custom Estimator with the code:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir=r'C:\record')
```

And this is my model function:

```
def cnn_model_fn(Images, labels, mode)
```

When the code running to estimator, the error occurs: ValueError: model_fn () must include features argument.
There is some other stuff that I am not sure if there is some help:

>

```
 INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpux9r74un
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_model_dir': 'C:Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpux9r74un', '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_is_chief': True, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_train_distribute': None, '_evaluation_master': '', '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x0000019AC007C1D0>, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_task_id': 0, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_task_type': 'worker', '_session_config': None, '_num_ps_replicas': 0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\headpose2.py", line 273, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\anaconda\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/headpose2.py", line 248, in main
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn)
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\anaconda\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 223, in __init__
    _verify_model_fn_args(model_fn, params)
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\anaconda\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1216, in _verify_model_fn_args
    raise ValueError('model_fn (%s) must include features argument.' % model_fn)
ValueError: model_fn (<function cnn_model_fn at 0x0000019AB5C0B048>) must include features argument.
```

Could anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Can you  provide your complete model function definition?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/yinguobing/cnn-facial-landmark/blob/master/landmark.py) This is the original code that I use.

Comment: What exactly is the ```Images``` object that you are passing?

Comment: >`def _train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(record_file="C:/Users/Desktop/cnn/record/train.record", batch_size=32, num_epochs=50, shuffle=True)`

>`def _eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(
            record_file="C:/Users/Desktop/cnn/record/evaluate.record",
            batch_size=2,
            num_epochs=1,
            shuffle=False)`

>`def _predict_input_fn():
    return input_fn(
            record_file='C:/Users/Desktop/cnn/record/test.record',
            batch_size=2,
            num_epochs=1,
            shuffle=False)`

Comment: I only changed three my own record path. These three records were made from the image dataset. They contain the tf_example like `tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': _int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': _int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': _bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': _bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': _bytes_feature(image_format),
        'label/points': _float32_feature(points),
    }`

Answer (score 2):

The `model_fn` function of an Estimator object **must** have the following signature: `model_fn(features, labels, mode, params)` where the names of the arguments are **fixed**. Therefore You can not replace `features` by `Images` as you did.

When using an Estimator, you also have to define an `input_fn` whose role is to prepare the data and feed them to the Estimator's `model_fn`. Both functions are connected under the hood by the Estimator class and I would say that the naming constraint was imposed so as to simplify this binding (and maybe others too).